# Serious XSRF bug in the new mobile theme

Tags: bug, status-completed

Here's a serious bug with [the new mobile theme that was rolled out](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/mobile-stack-exchange/).

`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/mobile/on` and `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/mobile/off` can be forced upon someone because they use GET rather than POST.

Comment: Hint: to switch back, go here: [`http://meta.stackoverflow.com/mobile/off`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/mobile/off).

Comment: You've probably just learned the combination to my luggage!

Comment: Click here to revert. [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/mobile/off](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/mobile/off) helpful link is helpful.

Comment: You have a funny definition for "serious". Wait - WHY IS ALL MY REP GONE?!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed.

More annoying than serious, but still a bug.

Comment: `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/mobile/on` doesn't work now.

Comment: @George - obviously.

Comment: How does one use the mobile theme now?

Comment: @George - the mobile link that's been on the bottom of every page for a day or two now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's dangerous, those actions just alter your session.

edit: I had attempted to trigger rep recalc, but that requires a POST apparently.  The OP mentioned actions work with a GET request.

Comment: Nope... not that I can tell.

Comment: No you didn't. Try harder!

Comment: Rep recalc had the same bug, but they fixed it pretty fast