# I'm seeing a very minimalistic version of the site. How do I get the full version again?

Tags: support, mobile-web, navigation, faq-proposed, preferences

I seem to have clicked on something that changed my display preferences. The main site is now very minimalistic, with fewer controls and different fonts.

I want to change it back, but where is it?

Answer (score 26):

Did you click on the "mobile" link shown in the footer? It could be you clicked on it by mistake.

[image: mobile link in footer]

If that is what happened, then the site would appear similarly to the following screenshot, taken for this very site. (The screenshot shows just part of the page.)

[image: mobile view of MSE]

If this is the case, you just need to click on the "full site" link that is present in the footer. In a browser that is not for a mobile device, it could seem the "full site" link is not really a link because the cursor shape is different, but clicking it changes back the site to the normal design.

[image: full site link in footer of mobile view]

Comment: And, as for that mouse cursor not being okay, kiamlaluno [figured out that problem too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108046/mouse-cursor-doesnt-change-to-pointer-when-hovering-full-site-on-mobile/108047#108047), @MrLister ;-)