# I'm getting a different Stack Overflow front page than normal

Tags: support, mobile-web

I am getting the different view of StackOverflow; I don't know why I am getting this view:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the mobile version of the site, which is served depending on the `user-agent` your browser sends us.

Check the footer to switch between mobile and regular versions of any Stack Exchange site, by clicking on the link in the footer that says

> **| mobile |**

or

> **full site**

Comment: As an aside: the "full" link doesn't seem to be a link, [but it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108046/mouse-cursor-doesnt-change-to-pointer-when-hovering-full-site-on-mobile/130015#130015). Just click it.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are getting the mobile view of Stack Overflow.

Perhaps your browser has an option to switch user agents or emulate a mobile browser? If so, check if it hasn't been enabled.

You could also have ended up on the mobile site by clicking the `mobile` link in the footer; there will be a `full site` link in the same place to switch back.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer...

Comment: Sorta, kinda, yeah. Edited to improve.