# Timestamp is truncated on mobile view for answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, mobile-web, timestamps

On my iPhone 4S (6.1.3), the answered timestamp is truncated (by different amounts) on various questions.
For example (from [jQuery select 'this' and another selector at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286253/jquery-select-this-and-another-selector-at-same-time/4286274#4286274)):

> [image]

<strike>No freehand circles unfortunately, as I'm posting from my mobile.</strike><sup>[Fixed!]</sup>
I am, however, reporting bugs from the poolside in Marrakesh, so I hope my dedication makes up for it.

Comment: This can even be seen in desktop Chrome, when clicking "mobile" in the footer. (To get back to the regular view, click "full site", [even though it doesn't look like it's clickable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108046/mouse-cursor-doesnt-change-to-pointer-when-hovering-full-site-on-mobile).)

Comment: There's no answer posted Nov 26 '10 (furthermore, the question was asked Mar 28 '12). Something weird's happened to the timestamps somewhere.

Comment: @michaelb958: Oops, that was me noobing and copying the wrong question URL. Fixed now (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286253/jquery-select-this-and-another-selector-at-same-time/4286274#4286274).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be available in the next deployment (`rev 2251` on meta and `rev 1609` on the network).