# Why is the code syntax color highlight gone in the mobile view?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code-block, mobile-web

The code block on a phone or tablet is only black/white.

**Update: example**
The code in the following link will have syntax color highlight in desktop browser.

[MVP Framework for winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874262/mvp-framework-for-winforms)

Here is the image of the mobile view. [mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkIrb.jpg)

Comment: Could you give an example post where this is happening? It could be an issue with language hints as well. Also, let us know your mobile phone/phone browser. Note that unsupported browsers will not get attention here on meta.

Comment: @Tim ManishEarth: If you click "mobile" at the bottom and look at an SO question with code, you'll find that its code isn't highlighted. This has bothered me as well, but not enough for me to open a meta thread on it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Hmm, I don't visit SO on mobile (but I use it for the rest of the sites), so I assumed this was browser-specific.

Comment: @TimManishEarth I've added an example.

Comment: @NickW I think Tim meant somthing like this http://imgur.com/hkdcX.jpg

Comment: You [cannot link to the mobile view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98925/serious-xsrf-bug-in-the-new-mobile-theme). So: just click the "mobile" link in the footer. And after that click "full site" (even though [the mouse cursor doesn't change for that link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108046/mouse-cursor-doesnt-change-to-pointer-when-hovering-full-site-on-mobile)) to get back.

Comment: @Arjan Feel free to create a better screen shot :P. [I used a Dolphin browser add on](http://dolphin-browser.com/add-ons/tools/screen-cut/) I guess I could have installed the Android SDK or rooted my phone to get something better but that was more than I was willing to do. Also and it never occurred to me to use the Mobile view from my desktop

Comment: (Nice, @SomeHelpfulCommenter, as you're using a non-stock browser I'm sure I don't need to explain anything to you! Cheers.)

Comment: WHAT there was code highlight on the mobile site? I never saw that and I'm using the mobile site for about 10 month...