# Print a stackoverflow page with long code block cropped

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code-block

The long code block will be stored in a scroll-able box. And printing will crop the code.

A workaround is switching to mobile view (by click the "**mobile**" at the bottom of the page). However, it will not color high-light the code (color printing code is very helpful). I have another question about it: 
[Why is the code syntax color highlight gone in the mobile view?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132636/why-is-the-code-color-highlight-gone-in-the-mobile-view)

Feature request:

1. Add syntax color highlight in the mobile view.
2. Provide a "print page" function/view.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite

Comment: @Flexo I've used the stack print app before. However, (1) it still doesn't have code syntax highlight. (2) it change the layout a little bit. (3) need to copy/paste the question ID...

Comment: Wasn't sure if you'd seen it or not. (And others finding this might not) There's a userscript that adds a print page button for it though which addresses 3) and 1) could probably be a feature request on that app