# Code blocks are not prettified on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, syntax-highlighting

On Chrome on Android, code blocks on the mobile site have no syntax highlighting, are not a monospaced font, and words are wrapped.

Mobile site on mobile browser:

[image]

Desktop site on mobile browser:

[image]

Inline code has the same issue, it isn't a monospaced font.

It has been this way for as long as I can remember. Wouldn't be surprised if this is a dupe.

Comment: @Paw too bad you weren't around [four years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132636/why-is-the-code-syntax-color-highlight-gone-in-the-mobile-view?noredirect=1)...

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. So highlighting should be fixed within next 24h.. However I can see one more issue on your screenshot which I can not reproduce: different font-family on code blocks.. It should be monospace but it looks like regular sans-serif font... I need to investigate that more. If you have any more details why is it like that, i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @Paweł just curious here. This was requested four years ago. Did you simply miss the request up to this day? (i.e. if someone would have bumped that old question, it would have helped?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wasn't SO employee 4 years ago. And also, there was a time, when mobile site wasn't the highest priority ever. Sooo not having enough resources to take care about low-priority stuff may delay some fixes (just a little bit :))

Comment: @Paweł I don't really know how to get more details but I'll try. Using my phone for any reason makes me extremely grumpy but I'll see if I can find out more.

Comment: @JasonC no problem at all. Can you give me info about your android device + android version? Have you customized anything? Like system/browser font or anything like that?

Comment: Nvm. I've find a way to reproduce that. Ok, fix should be visible in couple hours.

Comment: @Paweł I know, and thanks for taking care of this!

Comment: @Paweł Oh sweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've just added code highlighting to mobile code block. Thank you guys for bringing this up.