# How can I have my app access the mobile version of Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, mobile-web

I know about the "Mobile" link at the bottom of SE pages.

I want to make use of the mobile version of SE as part of an editor plugin I'm currently creating (don't ask *which* editor, I'm creating that too! lol).

However the mobile version doesn't seem to be working with a distinct URL.

So, how can it be accessed?

---

**P.S.** <del>*My guess: the culprit is a cookie setting `theme` to `2`. Am I right? Is there no other simpler workaround to get the mobile version?*</del> That was it! Answer posted below. :-)

Comment: Since this is for an app, it kinda feels like you should be [using the api](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs); there are search methods - look for `/search` - [live preview](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=mobile%20version&filter=default&site=meta&run=true)

Comment: @MarcGravell This is a fine idea, and exactly what I had in mind. However, at this early (mostly experimental) stage, I decided that forwarding to the results page would be enough. When it starts... growing a bit more, that's what I'm gonna do! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

URL is actually `{some_site}/mobile/on` to go to the mobile page and `{some_site}/mobile/off` to go to the full page. But...

```
StackExchange.switchMobile = function(e) {
    $.post("/mobile/" + e, {
         "returnurl": window.location.href
    }, function(e) {
         window.location.href = e;
    });
}
```

...as you can see, they use `post` method. Earlier it was [possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98925/serious-xsrf-bug-in-the-new-mobile-theme) to switch between mobile / full, but since they started to use `post` method, it is not possible anymore.

So now you can use:

- `StackExchange.switchMobile("on")` to switch to mobile version and `StackExchange.switchMobile("off")` to switch to the full (this is how mobile link works)
- `$.post("/mobile/on",function(){window.location.reload()});` to switch to mobile version and

  `$.post("/mobile/off",function(){window.location.reload()});`to switch to the full version

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though, to be honest I expected something more straightforward. I mean I just want to forward to a mobile search page: e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/mobile/search?q=search+for+sth`. It shouldn't be any more complicated than that...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon what do you mean "mobile search"?

Comment: OK. This http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beautify+css is a URL returning the search results from SO for the term `beautify css`. I want that very same thing, but the mobile version of the page.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon you can't force a theme change via GET url only, that's plain XSRF attack that's why it's possible only via a POST.

Comment: Just found a simple, no POST-related way I'm going to post right now. :-)

Comment: @Dr.K yeah, show it plz.

Comment: @nicael Just did. :-)

Answer (score 2):

@nicael and @Shadow Wizard are right in their explanation. However, put simply I wanted to retrieve a search page (in its mobile version) with a single request, inside a Cocoa Webview (no post-processing, no js, no nothing).

---

So, I looked into the HTTP headers AFTER setting the mobile view. And noticed an interesting thing : When Mobile mode is on, we are packing a `theme` cookie with the value `2`. (While, for the "Full Site" mode, `theme` is set to `0`).

And that's how I came up to the following very simple code, in Objective-C/Cocoa :

```
- (void)mobileSearchSO:(NSString *)searchFor
{
    // Format the search path
    NSString* searchPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%@",searchFor];
    NSURL* searchUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:searchPath];

    // Create the request
    NSMutableRequest* req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:searchUrl];

    // Create the cookie
    NSHTTPCookie* cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:@{
        NSHTTPCookieDomain  : @"stackoverflow.com",
        NSHTTPCookiePath    : @"/",
        NSHTTPCookieName    : @"theme",
        NSHTTPCookieValue   : @"2"
    }];

    // Set the cookie
    [req setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:@[cookie]]];

    // Load the request
    [[_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:req];
}
```

---

Tested and working fine. Enjoy! :-)

Comment: thats already looks like too programming question :DD Maybe it should be migrated to SO?

Comment: @nicael Haha! To be honest, while I'm a full-time SO addict, I'm not that familiar with Meta and I wasn't sure where to post it... I don't know. If someone thinks it should be migrated, let it be! :-)

Comment: "I'm a full-time SO addict" I already noticed :D Looking at your SO profile.

Comment: @nicael I don't know. Maybe it's that I keep considering the whole SE network, a totally programmer-oriented... domain. OK, with some of us interested in Photography, Buddhism, or whatever. (lol). But still programmers.

Comment: By the way,  I participate in SO too (because have some programming skills), but I am offering [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=bounties&sort=offered) of bounties :D

Comment: And, by the way, can you answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072508/in-the-playground-how-to-turn-off-debug-mode) question?

Comment: @nicael Hmm. Unfortunately not. I *am* using Xcode 6. But have absolutely no idea regarding "Playground"s...

Comment: Considering that you needed code for your iOS app and didn't mention it in your question my answer is completely useless now?

Comment: First-off, (it might be valid for iOS too though) it's for an OSX app. As for your answer, I think it's really useful, but a different approach. It's not "wrong" by any means. Rather informative too, I'd say. (Tried it myself, and it works fine)

Comment: Looks like it will work also for iOS.

Comment: It most likely will, but - given that I have around 1000x times more OSX-coding experience - I won't take any chances... lol